# Azure Logic App - How do I specify optional parameters "When a HTTP request is received"?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Good morning. I am new to logic apps and I'm wanting to add an optional parameter to the logic app shown below. I assume that if I specify it in the relative path it will always need to be provided, but maybe that's not the case. It's a boolean parameter, so perhaps there's a way to set a default of "false" if it's not provided? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set dynamic content and expression to achieve this:

[image]

```
if(equals(triggerOutputs()['relativePathParameters']['type'],'{}'),false,triggerOutputs()['relativePathParameters']['type'])
```

---

```
if(equals(triggerOutputs()['relativePathParameters']['year'],'{}'),false,triggerOutputs()['relativePathParameters']['year'])
```

And this is the official doc of the expression:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#if

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#equals

Comment: How will this solution allow me to call http://mindboggle.com/type/typeA rather than http://mindboggle.com/type/typeA/year/2005. If not, how do we declare an optional path parameter?